# SQL error (1054) Unknow column

Tags: sql

I have this long sql query here..

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
case when (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) < 0 and i.date < '2012-01-01' then (select ii.total from invoice ii where ii.client = c.clientid order by ii.invoiceid desc limit 1)  else (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) end as remaining,
case c.isactive+0
        when '1' then 'Stop'
        else 'Start' 
        end as Active
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```

I get an error with this query with the line `i.date < '2012-01-01'` saying that `i.date` is an unknown column in field list...how do I fix this?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Cosindering `date` is a reserved word on most DB's, you may need to encase it as necessary... `[date]` or with tick marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `alias i` out of the scope, which is defined here, in the subquery

```
(select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0)
```

with the `()`

you should change include this:

```
and i.date < '2012-01-01'
```

in both selects

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
case when (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0 and i.date < '2012-01-01' ) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0 and i.date < '2012-01-01' ) < 0 then (select ii.total from invoice ii where ii.client = c.clientid order by ii.invoiceid desc limit 1)  else (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid
where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) end as remaining,
case c.isactive+0
        when '1' then 'Stop'
        else 'Start' 
        end as Active
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```

Answer (score 0):

You're i.date is outside of the subquery. Right here

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
CASE WHEN 
    (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0)
    - 
    (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0)
    < 0 
    and i.date < '2012-01-01'  -- THIS IS NOT PART OF THE SUBQUERY
THEN 
    (select ii.total from invoice ii where ii.client = c.clientid order by ii.invoiceid desc limit 1)  
ELSE 
    (select ifnull(sum(total), 0) from invoice i where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p inner join invoice i on p.invoice = i.invoiceid where i.client = c.clientid and i.isdeleted = 0) 
END as remaining,
case c.isactive+0
        when '1' then 'Stop'
        else 'Start' 
        end as Active
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```